# If I like a post that is shared with friends but the original post was public, who can see that I liked the shared post?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-privacy

If I like a post that is shared by a friend with their friends but the original post was public, who can see that I liked the shared post?

In other words, if friend A (let's call her Anna) shares a post from a general page B (let's call this FB page Bananas) - and the original Bananas post was public but Anna is only sharing that bananas post with her friends, who can see my 'like' to this shared post?

Answer (score 1):

Your friends (who are following you) and your friend's (Anna's) friends will be able to see the '*like*' to the shared post as she has set the audience as *Friends*.

If you like the original post (which is posted publicly), everyone will be able to see the post.